# Exporting html div to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am developing an application in which I am using angular widget to create a dashboard. I have the following code in html which does the work for me as well as java script associated with it.

```
<div class="page" gridster="gridsterOptions">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="box" ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl" ng-dblClick="openSettings(widget)">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

At Runtime the user can add widgets to the page. Here is the HTML code when the user has added 2 widgets to the code.

```
<div class="page" gridster="gridsterOptions">
    <ul>
        <!-- ngRepeat: widget in dashboard.widgets -->
        <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" class="ng-scope gridster-item" style="margin: 0px; top: 5px; left: 5px; width: 130.167px; height: 137px;">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="box ng-scope layout-align-center-center layout-row" ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl" ng-dblclick="openSettings(widget)" tabindex="0">
            </div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-s"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-e"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-n"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-w"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-se"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-ne"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-sw"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-nw"></div>
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: widget in dashboard.widgets -->
        <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets" class="ng-scope gridster-item" style="margin: 0px; top: 147px; left: 5px; width: 806px; height: 705px;">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="box ng-scope layout-align-center-center layout-row" ng-controller="CustomWidgetCtrl" ng-dblclick="openSettings(widget)" tabindex="0">
            </div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-s"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-e"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-n"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-w"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-se"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-ne"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-sw"></div>
            <div class="gridster-item-resizable-handler handle-nw"></div>
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: widget in dashboard.widgets -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the user has created his dashboard page (in this case the top div element in the second html snippet) I need to send this html as a string to the server in order to load it later whenever he requests it. The reason behind it is the user would like to take a snapshot of the dashboard at run time with data filled in widgets. 
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
var content = document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML;
```

You can also use it to restore content of your dashboard:

```
document.querySelector('.page').innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot for the answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library, this can be made very easy...

```
// This code gets the html content from the page
var content = $(".page").html();

//This code sets the html content on the page to be a bold "Hello World"...
$(".page").html("<strong>Hello World</strong>");
```